# Splitting a string over multiple lines?

Tags: java, string

Let us suppose we have the following string:

```
String s1 = "This is a very long string which needs to be broken"
```

If the string's length is more than 30 characters, the string needs to be broken down so that each line should not contain more than 30 characters.

After splitting the output should be:

> "This is a very long string whi
>     ch needs to be broken"

I know I can use `String.split()`, but it doesn't suit my requirement.

What are the other possible ways to split it?

Comment: There is yet no basis or criteria for split. I need to split it if string length is more than 30.

Comment: I don't see a pattern of how one would want to break the string to begin with.  The length of each line is two, four, three, and two words in sequence.  We don't know enough about the requirements, or the way you would want to approach it, to answer this question reasonably.

Comment: We've well-established that, after a certain length, the string needs to be broken.  That's not the question; the question is, how **is** it broken?

Comment: I need to split it if string length is more than 30 characters

Comment: @shink you mean you want to limit the string length to 30 for each line?

Comment: Are you looking to split the string up such that the overall length of each line doesn't exceed 30 characters?  If that's so, ***please*** add that to your original question.

Comment: If it is all about splitting the string every 30 characters, this is probably not a big deal. If you are looking for more complex splitting than perhaps you should consider `java.text.BreakIterator` or create a subclass of it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `substring()`.

```
String str = "This is a very long string which needs to be broken";
int begin=0;
int end=str.length();
int lengthToWrap = 30;

while (str.length() > lengthToWrap) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(begin,begin+lengthToWrap));
    str=str.substring(begin+lengthToWrap,end);
    end=end-lengthToWrap;
}

System.out.println(str.substring(begin,end));
```

Comment: is not `str.length` but `str.length()`, and also, you need to fix a possible `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Don't underestimate yourself, just open your IDE and debug your program, it is not difficult as it seems and you can learn in the process :-)

Comment: I works for me now, +1, just something about it: don't hardcode that 30, what if the requirement changes to, say, 10? you would need to to the change on 4 lines

Comment: @morgano Did that too. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, must be time for lunch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache-common's [WordUtils.wrap()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#wrap%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

It can be used as

```
String res = WordUtils.wrap ("This is a very long string which needs to be broken", 30);
```

where `res` will be

```
This is a very long string\r\nwhich needs to be broken
```

Comment: Updated my answer which a trivial example - see javadocs for more examples/options

Answer (score -2):

In swift , to make large string as in new line or break in multiple lines.Just put `\n`. 
It worked for me.

For example : `"This string want to break from here then it shows like this"`

then just add \n (back slash n) only, do not add "" with this.

Now

```
"This string want to break from here **\n** then it shows like this"
```

*output :*

```
This string want to break from here
```

then it shows like this

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -3):

Read about "substring" & "split"

```
System.out.print(input.substring(0,7)+"\n"+input.substring(8,25)+"\n"+input.substring(27,51));
```

OR

```
String[] words = input.split(" ");
   System.out.print(words[0]+" "+words[1]+"\n"+words[2]+" "+words[3]+" "+words[4]+" "+words[5]+"\n"+words[6]+" "+words[7]+" "+words[8]+" "+words[9]+" "+words[10]);
```

Comment: This does not give the answer as expected.

Comment: Also, please make the code more flexible (e.g. use loop instead of hardcoded value). *What if the text has 300 characters instead?*

Comment: Well, the question was edited and my answer was for the question originally posted.Why down vote??